# DjangoORm:Apply order by on Foreign key fileds

Tags: django, django-orm

```
    class Game(models.Model):
          player = models.ForeignKey(place, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="place")
          ground = models.ForeignKey(country, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="place")
          total_score = models.ForeignKey(score, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="place")

   class Place(Time):
        child = models.CharField(max_length=100,  blank=True, verbose_name="child", db_index=True)
   class country(Time):
        child = models.CharField(max_length=100,  blank=True, verbose_name="country", db_index=True)

    class Time (models.Model):
        time =  models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="time")
```

I want to sort the data based on time

Django Orm to retrieve data & applying order by in descending order

```
Game.objects.filter(...).order_by('-player__time','-ground__time')
```

**Updated: Here I want to apply multiple order by on time field .
Desired output:
     What ever data which comes with oldest date come first & then newest one.Weather it is player or ground doesn't matter.**

Somewhere I am missing.Can someone point to the problem?

Comment: Your `Time` and `Game` models are not related. And you are totally messing up your db structure. Because the way it is now you can only have one player per game.

Comment: `Place` inherit from `Time` and this `QuerySet` is fine, just remove trailing whitespace from the end of the `order_by` argument. Try `Game.objects.filter(...).order_by('-player__time')`

Comment: Thats a mistake of trailing spaces.I tried with your ORM still not getting the desired output

Comment: @Sandy what is your desired output? It is ordered properly

Comment: Okay.Trying to figure it out.I don't see my data are properly ordered..

Comment: @Abdulafaja: Please see the updated Question.If you insist I will prepare one more Question. If it possible please the Updated Question

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look at [django docs for order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), You can see that what you're doing is *syntactically* correct.

**Edit**

The only thing that comes to my mind is that using concrete inheritance, leads into two separate tables for `Time` and `Place` and that's why the order_by is failing, It's worth trying to set `Abstract = True` in the `class Meta` for `Time`, since it doesn't make sense to have a Table for `Time`, and it's also hindering your query abilities.

```
class Time (models.Model):

   class Meta:
       abstract = True

    time =  models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="time")
```

Comment: I think as Place is inherited from time then no need of foreign key right?

Comment: @Sandy O I didn't see the inheritance, In this case I think if you put Abstract = True in the class Time, it's going to be alright.
Since Place and Time would have two separate Tables in the database, you'd run into problems not setting Time as Abstract. I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: I have already added Abstract=true in Time class. but no success

Answer (score 0):

In [Django QuerySet order_by doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) you can read that if you pass more than one field name into order_by it will sort results by fields one after another.

In that case you need to use [Django conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) and it is going to be something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, F, When, Value    

Game.objects.annotate(order_value=Case(
    When(player__time__gt=F('ground__time'), then=F('player__time')),
    default=F('ground__time'),
    output_field=CharField())).order_by('-order_value')
```

Comment: @Abdulafaja- You are using F() expression. but that doesn't addess my solution i guess